# Why is the standard contact structure on $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$ called "standard"?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, contact-geometry

The standard contact structure on $\mathbb R^{2n+1}=(x_1,y_1,\dots,x_n,y_n,z)$ is given by $\ker\alpha$, where $\alpha=dz-\sum_{i=1}^ny_idx_i$. But is there a reason why this contact structure is called "standard"? Is it just convention, or because it's the "nicest" contact structure, or is this contact structure actually natural in some important way?

Comment: Given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, consider the graph of f and its gradient, $G = \{ (x_1, \partial_1f, \dots, x_n,\partial_nf, f) \}$. The standard contact form $\alpha$ vanishes when restricted to this graph. Conversely, any $n$-dimensional submanifold on which $\alpha$ vanishes but the $n$-form $dx_1 \wedge\cdots\wedge dx_n \ne  0$ at every point is the graph of a function and its gradient. This is how the concept of a contact structure first arose.

Comment: Like in symplectic geometry, there is a Darboux theorem in contact geometry, which tells you that on a manifold with contact structure there is always a chart such that the given contact structure looks like the standard contact structure on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Forgiving historical inaccuracies (and perhaps eliding constants), I would wager it has something to do with the restriction of the (canonical) Liouville one form on $T^{*}\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to the unit co-sphere bundle with respect to the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that Darboux' theorem is a very good reason for calling this "standard".

Another reason is that it (one-point-)compactifies to the standard contact structure on the $(2n+1)$-sphere: this is the space of complex tangencies to $S^{2n+1}$, viewed as the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

I think Panagiotis Konstantis comment is the correct answer. To close the question: Any contact manifold is locally isomorphic to the standard contact structure on $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$ by the contact version of Darboux' theorem.

Comment: That is a bad reason. Actually, Darboux theorem shows that all contact structures are locally isomorphic. It can't be a reason to call one structure "standard".

Comment: You can find an embedding of $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ with the standard contact structure (not with the standard contact form) around each point of any contact $2n+1$-manifold. It's not just a local statement.